# Sympy: Custom subclass of Matrix not working

Tags: matrix, subclass, sympy

In sympy, I have written the following code to create a custom subclass for the class Matrix:

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols

class alsoMatrix(Matrix):
     def __init__(self,name):
         v0,v1,v2 = symbols(f'{name}[0:3]')
         super().__init__([v0,v1,v2])

my_matrix = alsoMatrix('v')
```

But all I get is this error:

```
Data type not understood; expecting list of lists or lists of values.
```

And yet, I did put a list of values. In fact, even if I get rid of the 'symbols' and enter [0,0,0] into the super initializing function instead, I get the exact same error. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Most sympy classes use `__new__` rather than `__init__`.

Comment: Just changed it to `__new__`, however I got the same error. @OscarBenjamin

Comment: Your code still implements an `__init__` method.

Comment: If I change both to `__new__`, I get an AttributeError saying that the `list` object has no attribute `_new`. @OscarBenjamin

Comment: With `__new__` you need the `cls` argument and you need to get the arguments for super right (it's different for classmethods).

Comment: Ok that seems to have done the trick. Thank you @OscarBenjamin. I'll add this answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. Sympy doesn't seem to use the `__init__` method to create new instances, but rather the `__new__` method, the syntax for which is slightly different. So I rewrote my code as the following:

```
from sympy import Matrix, symbols

class alsoMatrix(Matrix):
     def __new__(cls,name):
         v0,v1,v2 = symbols(f'{name}[0:3]')
         return super(alsoMatrix,cls).__new__(cls,[v0,v1,v2])

my_matrix = alsoMatrix('v')
```

This seems to have done the trick.